# Disconnected context was detected

Tags: c#

I got an error message in my c# application "Disconnected context was detected".
what is the cause of error? how to solve this problem?
here i am explaining my code flow.

I have starts a thread for data collection. It collects the data from com port and save the data in an EXCEl file.

DATA COLLECTION (THREAD) ---> SCAN 232 PORT (THREAD) ------ > PRINT TO EXCEL.

I found some reasons for this error from MSDN library. It says for MDA assistance. But i am not an Experienced developer in c#. So I could not understand the problem . Kindly help me to solve this.

This is not a full code for your reference i copied some portion which one i am using to create and write the excel file.

i am also facing one more problem.

### At the time of data writing on the excel, if i will open any other excel file , the current database file which one i am using in the code also will be open. how to solve this?

```
app = new Excel.ApplicationClass();

  Workbook1 = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

  Worksheet1 = (Excel.Worksheet)Workbook1.Worksheets[1];//ACtivating sheet-1 of workbook.


public bool Load_Excel_file(string Filename)
    {
        Excel_Filepath = Filename;

        try
        {
            if (Excel_Filepath  != "")
            {                

                Workbook1.SaveAs(Excel_Filepath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlXMLSpreadsheet,
               Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);


            }

            else
            {

                lbl_database.Text = "Database OFF";

            }

            if (ExcelFile_Select.Checked == true)
            {
                rbtn_database.Checked = true;          
                lbl_database.Text = "Collecting data on Database";
            }

            return (true);
        }
        catch
        {
            ExcelFile_Select.Checked = false;
            lbl_database.Text = "Database OFF";

            end_excel();       
            return (false);

        }

    }

 public void Print_to_Excel(object  exc_row_cnt_t, object  exc_col_cnt_t, object grid_row_cnt_t)
{
    Worksheet1 = (Excel.Worksheet)Workbook1.Worksheets.Add(Type.Missing, (Excel.Worksheet)Workbook1.Worksheets[Sheet_Num++], Type.Missing, Type.Missing); 
try{

            for (int column_count = 1; ((column_count) < Grid_Collect_Data.ColumnCount - UNUSED_CELLS); column_count++)
            {
                if ((Grid_Collect_Data.Rows[grid_row_cnt].Cells[column_count].Value) != null)
                {
                    ((Excel.Range)Worksheet1.Cells[exc_row_cnt, (exc_col_cnt * (Grid_Collect_Data.ColumnCount - UNUSED_CELLS )) + column_count ]).Value2 = (Grid_Collect_Data.Rows[grid_row_cnt].Cells[column_count].Value).ToString();
                    ((Excel.Range)Worksheet1.Cells[exc_row_cnt, (exc_col_cnt * (Grid_Collect_Data.ColumnCount - UNUSED_CELLS)) + column_count]).HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;
                }
            }


  Workbook1.Save();
 }
  catch (Exception e)
        {
            end_excel();           

            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "Wireless Sensor Network", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

        }

 }
 void end_excel()
    {


        Workbook1 = null;
        Worksheet1 = null;
        app.Quit();
        app = null;
        if (Worksheet1 != null)
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Worksheet1);
        if (Workbook1 != null)
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Workbook1);
        if (app != null)
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
        Workbook1 = null;
        Worksheet1 = null;
        app = null;

        GC.Collect();
        Excel_app_run = false;
        Is_Load_Report = false;


    }
```

Error Message :

Context 0x1a1178' is disconnected.  Releasing the interfaces from the current context (context 0x1a1008).This may cause corruption or data loss. 
To avoid this problem, please ensure that all contexts/apartments stay alive until the applicationis completely done with 
the RuntimeCallableWrappers that represent COM components that liveinside them.

Comment: OK, we need way more details here. What technology are you using (OLEDB for example), can you give some source code of what you're trying to do? Cheers.

Comment: Sorry the source code is a big one. I am using System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject

Comment: app = new Excel.ApplicationClass();

            Workbook1 = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

            Worksheet1 = (Excel.Worksheet)Workbook1.Worksheets[1];//ACtivating sheet-1 of workbook.

Comment: I've added your comment to the question but this is just a fragment. How/where do you push this to the main-thread?  Exact error message and stack dump might help. And the code around the origin of the exception.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. now i add the exact error message pls look at this.but sorry i could not post the code due to size problem. just i explain how i save in excel.This application for a wireless module. At the time of form loading i create an excel file (using save as with file name). and start a main thread to start a datacollection.Inside this tread , i am starts another thread for scan232 port. It collects the data and write on the workbook.scan232 port using a timer intervel of 1 minute. It always scan the port and write to excel and save.

Comment: this problem arise when i am frequently saving excel file. Before that i dont have any error on my application.

Comment: You can always post a few (relevant) lines of code, there is no size problem then. Right now this is unanswerable.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I'm using Outlook and I got a similar error when trying to access the Outlook Object Model on a thread other than the 'main thread'.  In my outlook add-in I also have a Windows form and on the windows form I was starting a new thread that began a long running operation that needed to access the Outlook Object Model.  In addition, this thread was trying to update a progress bar on the Windows Form at certain milestones.  I made 2 changes that seemed to fix the issue based on the article below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8sesy69e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#feedback

Changes I made:

- Change the thread to single threaded apartment
- Remove the code that fires the event to update the progress bar on the main thread

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question, the issue is that Excel when opened shows your file?  This is expected all your doing with your code is manipulating the Excel application. So Excel will show your file, it doesn't 'know' its a not a users file.

If you really don't want this then not using COM/Interop is the way forward.
Look into the [OpenXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) library, and the [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/) library which makes working with the former and Excel very easy.

Finally if you're really trying to write every minute...Excel is NOT the format you want to be writing too.  Look at plain text, XML or maybe a embedded database of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same message when running an Excel VSTO workbook in Visual Studio's debug mode. It fixed it to build the workbook, exit the IDE and run it directly.

Answer (score -5):

You can remove the exception by disabling exception from:

1. Select project.
2. Goto menu: Debug->Exceptions
3. Goto Managed Debugging exception. And remove check from exception type, you experienced.

Comment: This is not a good solution.  Turning off the warning is like removing the 'low fuel' bulb in your car instead of actually putting gas in your car.  It merely hides the fact that there is a problem.  The MDA monitor finds bugs that would otherwise be impossible to find using the Debugger and stepping through code.  This error is telling the developer about a thread context switch issue.

Comment: I would downvote this answer if my account allowed me to

Comment: @publicwireless you should come back now that you can and give it the mighty downvote.